# Thesis submitted, but not published – can I put the title on my CV?

Tags: phd, thesis, cv

My thesis was submitted, but not published by the library or online yet.

I would like to put its title on my CV. Is this OK? Or is it kind of risky?

Comment: Has it been accepted/signed off by your committee?  If so, and the only reason it isn't in the library is due to embargo (to allow time for filing patents, submitting journal articles, etc) then you can say "To appear (date)".

Comment: It's only submitted, not accepted yet

Comment: What kind of risks in particular are you worried about? The only generally important thing is that the information in your C.V. must be accurate. If your thesis has been submitted, but not accepted, then say "(submitted)".

Comment: So i can add the title of thesis?

Comment: I don't see any reason not to. But as has been pointed out, you need to make clear the status of your thesis.

Answer (score 8):

There is no obvious reason why including the title of your thesis in your CV might be risky. Just make sure that all information is presented accurately. If your thesis has been submitted, but not accepted, then say "(submitted)".

Answer (score 0):

You wrote the paper, and know the material, so yes, you can cite your paper. Just make sure that its (submitted/unpublished) status is disclosed correctly.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, just ask your supervisor.  The risk is to your university if it turns out totally bogus.

Comment: It's not Martin's responsibility to ask his supervisor. If the title is bogus, then it's the university's fault for setting him up with a bogus thesis title.

Comment: What is this "setting him up with a [...] thesis title" of which you speak?  A PhD thesis is the work of the student; that includes the title.  (Of course, every PhD student should get preliminary feedback from their advisor before submitting their thesis, including feedback on the title, not to mention regular feedback on the developing content over the preceding several months/years.)

Comment: @JeffE: My thoughts went into the same direction as the part in brackets. In addition, the direction of the PhD thesis is often heavily influenced by the advisor, even if the phrase "set him up with" might actually be too strong in general.